# Copy data from a row in one table to a row in another table based on information from a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have moved an expiration date from one table to another. Since I created the new column, some new dates have been added, but most are still set to NULL.

I need to copy the dates from the original table and column (a) to the new table and column (b) only if b is NULL and this is marked as a system.

I have created the below statement, but it throws an error. I think I might have to use FROM, but I'm relatively new to T-SQL, and have had no experience with it before. Does anyone see where I have made my mistake?

```
UPDATE purchs
SET purchs.dexpiredate = client.dexpire
FROM
INNER JOIN client ON client.iclientid = purchs.iclientid
INNER JOIN feature ON purchs.ifeatureid = feature.ifeatureid
WHERE feature.lsystem = 1 and purchs.dexpiredate IS NULL
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE p
SET p.dexpiredate = c.dexpire
FROM purchs p
INNER JOIN client c ON c.iclientid = p.iclientid
INNER JOIN feature f ON f.ifeatureid = p.ifeatureid
WHERE 
f.lsystem = 1 and 
p.dexpiredate IS NULL
```